# Check what appsetting.json file is in use by the API App

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

Got an API app written with ASP.NET Core (3.1). I deploy it to a Kubernetes cluster in a Docker container. Sure thing the appsettings.json holds lots of values that need to be changed, depending on the environment, so I use a well-known trick with the environment variable substitution in the release pipeline. My code looks like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static IWebHostEnvironment _env { get; }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
    {
        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
            {
                config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
                config.AddJsonFile($"secrets/appsettings.{_env}.json", optional: true);
                var root = config.Build();
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
    }
}
```

That being said, I set the environment variable in a container, and the app supposed to pick-up the right file from the disk. The problem is, I have a suspicion the wrong appsettings file is used. Is there a reliable way to check what appsettings.json file the app uses?
Not sure if displaying the file name and the environment name via the API would be a good idea, but I need a way to check those without logging-in inside the container. Any samples and suggestions for the matter would be much appreciated.

Comment: Should you using `_env.EnvironmentName` while adding Json file?

Comment: a simple solution is just logging what's important (in this case it's categorized as `information`). You of course should have some way to view/access your log files or logging data. It is required.

Comment: Good catch with ```_env.EnvironmentName```. I missed that

Comment: Logging this data as an info message might be helpful. I'll probably try to add this info to a log when the app starts in the container. Thanks!